# existence of a solution of a differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, cauchy-problem

we have a continuous function $\omega:\mathbb{R}_+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_+ $ such that
$$      p'(t)=\omega(p(t))\\
      p(0)=0$$

has only the trivial solution $p=0$ on $J=[0,b]$.
Now the author claims, that there are functions $p_n$ such that  $$p_n'(t)=\omega(p_n(t))+\frac{1}{n}\\
      p(0)=\frac{1}{n}$$

for all $t\in J$ and $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}p_n=0$.

I understand the limit, but i really dont know why we have such functions $p_n$ on the whole interval $J$. Thanks for your help!

Edit: The statment should only be true for $n>N$.

Comment: Picard's theorem !!!

Comment: Picard-Lindelöf shouldnt work here, because we dont know if $\omega$ is lipschitz continuous.

Comment: You could add and calculate an example like $ω(p)=p^2$ so that you get dynamical blow-up for positive initial values. Does the text say something on how $b$ is chosen? The zero solution is valid globally, as obviously $ω(0)=0$. There are no restrictions on $b$ from this side. Or is the existence claim only valid for $n>N_b$?

Comment: @Skimann, on the other hand, we do not need $p_n$ to be unique, so maybe there is no need for Picard-Lindelof.

Comment: Yes Picard's didn't work sorry!!! L.Continutiy alas !!!! 

Comment: @lutz Lehmann he only states, that by our assumption on $\omega$ there are such functions $p_n$ with the above properties. So yea i think it is only true for $n>N$.

Comment: Another less constructed situation for this kind of behavior is a saddle point in the plane. There are 2 solution curves that converged towards it, and two that move away from it. Every other solution that starts close to the converging solution will first stay close and on approach to the saddle point switch to the diverging regime. The time it stays close is the longer the closer the initial point is to the converging solution curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The authors did so because they wanted to used Peano existence theorem. Note that the Peano's theorem requires the domain to be an open subset.
2. The such existence is not true for all $n$. The solution for any induced ODE may explode before reaching time $b$. For example, consider $\omega (x)=x^2$.
3. For $n$ sufficiently large, the mentioned existence is valid. The proof idea is to replace $\omega$ by another bounded continuous function $\tilde{\omega}$ such that these two functions are identical in a neighborhood of $0$. Then thanks to the boundedness of $\tilde{\omega}$, the coresponding solutions $(\tilde{p}_n)$ will not explode. After that prove what you have claimed $\lim \tilde{p}_n=0$. From which you can show that when $n$ is sufficiently large, $\tilde{p}_n$ is also a solution of ODE $p'=\omega(p)+\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: 1. Hmm i think for Peano we need a closed subset?  2. Yea it should be $n>N$. 3. I understand your proof, but i dont see how i get a solution for the whole interval or am I wrong? Or can you please be a bit more explicit

Comment: 1. You can state it with closed sets, however, they should contain an open neighborhood of $(t_0,x_0)$. 2. Ok. 3. Which part you have problems with? By the boundedness of $\tilde{\omega}$, $\tilde{p_n}$  is defined even on $\mathbb{R}_+$.